# Searching number of relationships in Core Data - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My Core Data Model has two entities: Locations and Photos.

Location stores lat, lon and can have many photos associated to it.
Photos store a picture as binary data. Inverse relationships are set as well.

For a given location how can I see if that entity currently has any photos associated with it?

I'm using an NSManagedObject class for locations and thought about searching through all photos, but that seemed rather inefficient.

```
class Location: NSManagedObject, MKAnnotation {
    init (latitude: Double, longitude: Double, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

        if let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Location", inManagedObjectContext: context) {
            super.init(entity: ent, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

            self.latitude = NSNumber(double: latitude)
            self.longitude = NSNumber(double: longitude)
        }
        else {
            fatalError("ERROR")
        }
    }

    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    }

    func photoCount(context: NSManagedObjectContext) ->Int {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Photo")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "location = %@", self)

        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        ??? Best Option ???

        return <COUNT OF PHOTOS FOR LOCATION>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this much more difficult than necessary. Since you say that there's a relationship from `Location` to `Photo`, all you need to do is look up the value of that relationship. When you already have a `Location`, you can use its relationships directly without doing another fetch.

If you have

```
let location : Location = // assume this exists
```

And if `Location` has a to-many relationship called `photos` to entity `Photo`, you get the count of photos as

```
let count = location.photos?.count
```